# Awk - Different FS for each matched line

Tags: awk

I am using awk to match specific lines in a log file. Depending on the line it matches I want to use a different FS. I want to do something like what I have below but it isn't working. Is it possible?

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
if ( $0 ~ "good.morning" ) 
{ FS=","; print $1 }
if ( $0 ~ "good.evening" )
{ FS=";"; print $2 }
```

I realize I can set FS in a { BEGIN } section of the script. Or I can set FS when calling the script. But I'm hoping to have finer control of the FS per matched record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it the following way:

```
$ cat data
ONE 1 I
TWO 2 II

THREE:3:III
FOUR:4:IV
FIVE:5:V

SIX 6 VI
SEVEN 7 VII

$ ./awkscript data
I
II

III
IV
V

VI
VII
$
```

`awkscript` is as follows:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
{
    if ( $0 ~ /:/ )
    {
        FS=":";
        $0=$0
    }
    else
    {
        FS=" ";
        $0=$0
    }
    #print the third field, whatever format
    print $3
}
```

`$0=$0` re-evaluates fields according to the current `FS`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem there is that the `FS` is generally used to separate the line into fields *as it's read in.* The basic flow of `awk` is:

- Execute pre-read commands.
- For each line:

  - Separate line into fields.
  - Execute line-based commands.
- Execute post-read commands.

You can see that with the transcript:

```
pax> ( echo '1 2 3'; echo '4;5;6' ) >inputdata
pax> awk '{FS=";"; print $2} inputdata
2
5
```

The `1 2 3` line is separated into fields *before* the body is run, so the setting of `FS` will only affect subsequent lines.

So, yes, you *can* change the field separator at line level but it usually has to be done *before* the line is read (such as in the processing of the *previous* line).

However, there is a slightly tricky way to actually force `awk` to *re-parse* the line, simply by setting it equal to itself. First we change *both* lines in the input to use `;` as a field separator:

```
pax> ( echo '1;2;3'; echo '4;5;6' ) >inputdata
```

The we run the script style which you originally thought may work:

```
pax> awk '{FS=";"; print $2}' inputdata

5
```

As you can see from that first example, the line `1;2;3` is put into a single field because white space is being used as the separator. Hence field number two is blank. Contrast that with:

```
pax> awk '{FS=";"; $0 = $0; print $2}' inputdata
2
5
```

Adding `$0 = $0` into the mix after changing the `FS` variable caused `awk` to re-parse the line using the modified separator, and therefore repopulate `$1`, `$2` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Because `FS` has to be set to the value you want before Awk reads the line, the simplest workaround is probably to explicitly `split` instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
/good.morning/ { split($0,a,","); print a[1] }
/good.evening/ { split($0,a,";"); print a[2] }
```

(I'm guessing you really mean `good\.morning` etc but never mind me.)

Comment: Nvm was one I'd not heard before so it may be better to spell it out in full. Especially since one of the definitions (http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nvm) states "You were too stupid to understand what I was talking about so I gave up" and I'm assuming you don't want to risk offending the OP :-)